# identical Services in Angular - multiple instances? or pass parameters in each call?

Tags: angular

I'm building a component in Angular that controls & monitors a relay via a REST API.  There are several identical relays, each with their own name and IP address.

I'm an Angular noob, and don't quite understand the "providedIn: 'root' vs 'any'" paradigm and how services are "injected".  Should I be creating a single service (shared by all instances of the component), and passing in the API endpoint each time I want to make a call to a specified API?  Or should I be creating a separate instance of the service for each relay?

If the answer is the former, would it be different if the service(s) needed to keep a persistent TCP connection to each relay, instead of the stateless HTTP connections?

An am I barking up the wrong tree by looking at the "providedIn: 'any'" business?  I've been trying to figure out how to pass parameters (e.g. the API endpoint) into the constructor of the Service, and it seems to be surprisingly uncommon information.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass parameters to the constructor of the service from the component, because the service is necessarily constructed *first* and provided to the component.  Such is just the Angular way.  Instead, it seems that the idiom is to ensure that the service is local to the component by including the service in the providers array in the control's metadata (rather than in the providers array for the *app*)

```
// in some.component.ts ...
@Component({
  selector: 'some-component',
  template: `<div>[my control here]</div>`,
  providers: [ SomeService ]  //provide this service locally!
})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() url:string = 'http://blah.com';

  constructor(private myService:SomeService) { } //SomeService gets injected here

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myService.remoteEndpoint = this.url;  //set the url in the service here!
  }
}
```

and using "providedIn: 'any'" (rather than "providedIn: 'root'" in the "injectable" decorator for the service:

```
// in some.service.ts ...
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'any'
})
export class SomeService {
  remoteEndpoint:string = '';
  constructor() {  }
}
```

Check out [this Angular doc](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action) for a discussion of "sandboxing" vs "singleton" services.